# How to get things in txt and store in array in c

Tags: c, inventory

I am a noob in programming, so don't blame me if the code below isn't good. I am doing a project about an inventory system. there is five function in this system including modify and search. My thought is to let user input record number and gets the data stored in txt back to the array and display the one with correct ID.With this, user can edit the thing is the certain structure array. But I can't figure out how to get data in txt to an array.
it is poissibe or any alternative solution.

declaraton

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define true 1
 #define false 0
struct RecordData {

     char RecordNum[10]; 
     char ItemName[ 50 ]; 
     int ItemNum ; 
     char Category[ 50 ];
     int Quantity;
     char Recipient[ 50 ];
     char Destination[ 50 ];
     char Delivery[ 100 ];

}; 
struct RecordData record[MAX];
FILE *fp;
```

Function add record

```
int addrecord(){

    int x, i = 0;
    char ch, yesno;
    char space = ' ';

    doagain:

        printf("1) Enter Record Number:");
        gets(record[i].RecordNum);

        printf("2) ItemName\nEnter :");
        gets(record[i].ItemName);

        printf("3) ItemNumber\nEnter :");
        scanf("%d%c", &record[i].ItemNum, &ch);

        printf("4) Category\nEnter : ");
        gets(record[i].Category);

        printf("5) Quantity\nEnter : ");
        scanf("%d%c", &record[i].Quantity, &ch);

        printf("7) Recipient\nEnter : ");
        gets(record[i].Recipient);

        printf("8) Final Destination\nEnter : ");
        gets(record[i].Destination);

        printf("9) Delivery status \nEnter : ");
        gets(record[i].Delivery);

        fp = fopen("stock.txt", "a");

        fprintf(fp, "%04d\n", i);

        fprintf(fp, "%s\n%d\n%s\n%d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%c\n", record[i].ItemName, record[i].ItemNum, 
        record[i].Category, record[i].Quantity, record[i].Recipient, record[i].Destination, record[i].Delivery, space);
        fclose(fp);

    enterys:

        printf("Do you want to add other record? Yes(Y) or No(N)");
        scanf("%s", &yesno);

    switch (yesno){

        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            i++;
            goto doagain;
            break;
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
            printf("end program\n");
            system("cls");
            return main();
            break;
        default:
            printf("you have enter wrong input");
            goto enterys;

    }

}
```

main

```
int main(){

    int num;
    char space, ch;
    mainGUI:
        printf("1. Add New Item<s>:");
        printf("\n2. Display Item Record:");
        printf("\n3. Search Item Information:");
        printf("\n4. Modify Item Record<s>:");
        printf("\nDelete Item Record<s>:");
        printf("\nWhat is your option? <1-5>");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        system("cls");

        switch (num)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Quit^_^");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("You Are Now Adding New Item<s>:\n");
                addrecord();
                break;
            case 2:

                printf("You Are Now Displaying Item<s>:");
                display();
                printf("Press any Button to Go Back Menu");
                scanf("%c%c", &ch, &space);
                if (space == ' '){

                    system("cls");  
                    goto mainGUI;   

                }else{

                    system("cls");
                    goto mainGUI;

                }

                break;
            case 3:
                printf("You Are Now searching items New Item<s>:");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("You Are Now Adding New Item<s>:");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("You Are Now Adding New Item<s>:");
                break;
            default:
            printf("Enter Wrong input\n");
            goto mainGUI;
            break;




        }
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Alternative solution? A database.

Comment: The project required me to use c language. I would if the required not like that

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. Ever.

Comment: why? use scanf("%s", &char) instead?

Comment: [`gets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gets.html) is considered as insecure (prone to buffer overruns) and, hence, was deprecated and excluded from standard. Please, use [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) instead. It has a parameter for buffer length. Therefore it is more safe than `gets()`. It can be called with `stdin` as well, so, `gets()` isn't needed actually. Btw. `scanf("%s", &char)` is prone to buffer overruns as well but you could add width specifier to format to make it safe.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Reading from or writing to a text file? You include an `addrecord() ` function in your question, but it prompts the user for the information to enter, not reads from a file.

Comment: actually, I want to show how I put data to the txt file. I don't sure whether it affects. My  aim is to let user enter record then the user can search and display it in terminal. Futher more edit the record

Comment: So your question is: "How to write a function that reads the file created by `addrecord` and save the data in an array", correct?

Comment: yup. it is because I have no idea how to read the thing in txt and store in to a array

Comment: Look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c+read+text+file+into+array+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK_e7DwvveAhWEo4sKHaCkC-IQrQIoBDAAegQICRAM&biw=1920&bih=963 There are plenty of examples to get you started

Comment: OT: `return main();` ==> `return 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout below mentioned fragment. This should ring some bells.

```
fp = fopen("stock.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL){
  printf("Cannot open file \n");
  return 0;
}

i = 0;
ch[i] = fgetc(fp);
while (ch != EOF){
  i++;
  ch[i] = fgetc(fp);
}
fclose(fp);
return 1;
```